# KIVY collide_point RelativeLayout vs StencilView

Tags: kivy, android-relativelayout

I started learning KIVY from Kivy – Interactive Applications and Games in Python - Second Edition by Roberto Ulloa". 
I was trying to understand collide_point with a sample program.

In RelativeLayout with the below sample code, I am able to identify when mouse gets clicked on horizontal line. But if I use StencilView, I am unable to catch touch event.

Any help please

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView


class MyPaintWidget(Scatter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        self.selected = None
        self.touched = False
        super(MyPaintWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def create_figure(self,  **kwargs):
        (ix,iy) = self.to_local(*self.pos)
        (fx,fy) = self.to_local(self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1] + self.size[1])
        print ("ix " + str(ix) + " iy " + str(iy) + " fx " + str(fx) + " fy " + str(fy))
        self.canvas.add(Line( points=[ix, iy, fx, fy], width=1))
        return self

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
           #This print I get for RelativeLayout
           #But for StencilView it does not work when I touch the line
           print("Hi you touched the line")

class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        #If parent is StencilView unable to click
        #but if parent is RelativeLayout, I am able to get collide_point
        #parent = StencilView()
        parent = RelativeLayout()
        #parent = Scatter()
        ix = 100.
        iy = 100.
        fx = 200.
        fy = 100.
        pos = (min(ix, fx), min(iy, fy))
        size = (abs(fx-ix), abs(fy-iy))

        self.painter = MyPaintWidget(pos=pos, size=size)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter.create_figure())
        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Comment: One note. The `collide_point()` method checks for collision with the `Widget` (in your case `MyPaintWidget`) and has nothing to do with any `canvas` instructions. So, you are not actually checking with touch the line.

Comment: Thanks. But even if collide_point checks for the widget (MyPaintWidget) why is it not getting triggered for StencilView but for RelativeLayout i.e. in my sample program, if you make parent as StencilView() instead of RelativeLayout, collide_point is not triggered when I touch the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.stencilview.html) for `StencilView` says:

> Note
>
> StencilView is not a layout. Consequently, you have to manage the size
>   and position of its children directly. You can combine (subclass both)
>   a StencilView and a Layout in order to achieve a layout’s behavior.

So, the `size` that you set for its children will be used and `size_hint` is ignored. That results in a `size` for your `MyPaintWidget` of `(100.0, 0.0)` per your calculations. And a height of 0 will never return a `True` value for `collide_point()`.

However, when you use `RelativeLayout`, `size_hint` is not ignored, and since the default value for `size_hint` is `(1,1)`, your `MyPaintWidget` ends up with a size the same as your `App`. Your calculated `size` is ignored, and you get `True` results for most of your `collide_point()` calls.

To get consistent results, add `size_hint=(None, None)` to your `MyPaintWidget(pos=pos, size=size)`. Of course, with a `height` of 0, you will never get a collision.